# Azure Function Failing on portal with Exception: System.TimeoutException

Tags: azure, timeoutexception, azure-function-app

I am new to Azure development and developed a function app

I published my function app to Azure portal. It is working fine on my development machine but on portal it's throwing following exception (some times) 
**The operation 'ScanLogs' with id '2eggec6de-54f5-4t34-5423-afffce5c6a43' did not complete in '00:02:00'.**

I couldn't find solution to this error. Can somebody help me to understand what this error is about and why we get this?

following is timeout specified in host.json in prod.
[image]

Comment: In short: the operation 'ScanLogs' is taking too much time. Is it waiting for resources? What's the code? Did you add logging? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: this is a BlobTriggerred function app, we move files to storage account. I have no logs, but enables Application Insights for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of function you are running check here for the exact syntax in host.json - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json-v1

The default timeout for a function on the consumption plan is 2 minutes, if you need it to run longer then change/add the functiontimeout value, i.e.

```
"functionTimeout": "00:05:00",
```

in host.json.

NB: On a Consumption plan this can't be more than 10 minutes so if you need it to run longer either find a way to break up your function into smaller chunks and maybe use a Durable function [fan=out fan-in pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup) or change it to run on a dedicated App Service Plan where it can run for as long as you like but obviously you'll have to pay to have the server running 24/7

Comment: I am using Elastic Plan for my function app and in my host.json I have specified functionTimeout to be 3 hours.
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "03:00:00"
}
Today when I checked my application insight I have exception message: The operation 'ScanContainer' with id '00959070-cfc4-4b5e-9529-49408f52226f' did not complete in '00:02:00'.

Comment: If you got that message then it definitely timed out, have you ensured that the change to 3 hours has been deployed correctly check the Function app settings link in the portal for your function as that will show you the current host,json deployed

Comment: It's confirmed in function app host.json it is 3 hours. I updated question with attachment.